# Get selected value of paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, polymer

I'm using polymer's [`paper-dropdown-menu`](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-dropdown-menu.html) as a dropdown menu for my project. Now i want to get the value of selected option, when a user selects an option from the dropdown.

Here's the HTML structure

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Color" class="text-color-labels">
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
        <core-menu class="menu" id="textColor">
            <paper-item value="#000000">Black</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#522A19">Dark Brown</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#7D331E">Light Brown</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#EDCCBA">Tan</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#B89325">Old Gold</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#B7A967">Vegas Gold</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="#29753A">Kelly Green</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

I tried to get value using this code:

```
$("body").on("core-select", ".text-color-labels", function(){
    var selectedItem = document.querySelector('#textColor').selectedItem;
    var selectedColor = selectedItem.textContent;
    console.log(selectedColor); //gives Black, Dark Brown, Light Brown etc
})
```

But it doesn't gives me the value of the dropdown. How to get that?

Comment: If `core-select` is an event from your framework it would be possible that the selected value will pass to the callback function as parameter?!

Comment: If this is the correct [link](https://github.com/Polymer/core-selection/blob/master/core-selection.html#L121) to this library, it seems that when this `core-select` event is fired, it also sends `item` with it: `this.fire("core-select", {isSelected: isSelected, item: item});`

Comment: The first thing i read on the doc is that you can access the selected item with `detail.item`. The event will fired when an item was selected AND deselected so you should check that too with `detail.isSelected`

Comment: @marcel i passed parameter `e` to the event function and tried to use `e.detail.item` and `e.detail.isSelected`. Both are `undefined`

Comment: Inside your callback function for `core-select` event put a `console.log(arguments);` and post results here please.

Comment: it gave `Arguments { 0: Object, 2 more… }`

Comment: If you expand the first Object or those `2 more...` could you find anything related to `isSelected` or `item`?

Comment: There is nothing related to `isSelected` or `item`. However, there is `target` object which has a `selected` property. So i used `arguments[0].target.selected` and it worked.

Comment: @Kanav could you able to post working code ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Polymer 1.0 you can use `on-iron-select` attribute in `paper-dropdown-menu`. For example:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Color" class="text-color-labels" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
```

Polymer function:

```
  _itemSelected : function(e) {
    var selectedItem = e.target.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
      console.log("selected: " + selectedItem.innerText);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Don't use selectedItem, prefer using 
var selectedId = e.target.selected;

Answer (score 0):

Update your event handler as so:

```
$("body").on("core-select", ".text-color-labels", function(e) {
    var selectedItem = e.target.selected,
        selectedColor = selectedItem.textContent;
    console.log(selectedColor); //gives Black, Dark Brown, Light Brown etc
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Color" class="text-color-labels" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
```

If you want the selected item value:

```
_itemSelected : function(e) {
    var selectedItem = e.target.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
        console.log("selected: " + selectedItem.value);
    }
}
```