# getting values off of dropdown-menu in polymer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, polymer-1.0

So i need to submit a project tomorrow and i know that i am a tad bit late but please help me.
I don't know how to extract value from a paper-dropdown-menu and pass it on to a php page using javascript.

All the other values are being passed on except this dropdown-menu

the dropdown-menu code is

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu id="drop" label="select course" placeholder="IF">
            <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="IF" attr-for-selected="value">
        <paper-item value="IF">IF</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="CO">CO</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="EJ">EJ</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>

                </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

And i want to fetch the value IF CO or EJ and pass it to a php variable
Please Help

PS. I am a Noob to this and i know very little javascript so please code as much as you can. Every little help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any error you are getting .?

Comment: no error but i want those values because they fill in the database

Comment: Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961409/get-selected-value-of-paper-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu 
            valueattr="label_value" 
            on-core-select="{{get_dd_value}}">

          <paper-item label="opt1" label_value="1"></paper-item>
          <paper-item label="opt2" label_value="2"></paper-item>
</paper-dropdown-menu>     

//JS part:
get_dd_value: function(e, detail) {
          var value = detail.item.attributes.label_value.value;
}
```